# Как заменить экран входящих вызовов на Android?

Tags: java, android

**Дано:** есть приложение [Ultimate Call Screen HD](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1575395) - аналогичных приложений на маркете довольно много.

**Вопрос:** как это работает? Как написано?

У кого какие идеи?

P.S. Ориентируемся на нерутованные аппараты.

Comment: В теории нужно написать приложение которое заменит стандартный Dialer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029183/android-dialer-application

Comment: Я полагаю что это не так. Указанное приложение не заменяет дайлер, а лишь декорирует его.

Comment: на сколько я помню, даже у тех прог. нет 100%  качественного решения, нет, нет да все равно проскакивает стандартный экран диаллера.

Comment: Тем не менее хотелось бы понимать устройство этого чуда. Ну не заниматься же реверс-инжинирингом :)

Comment: @Barmaley: что ж вы реверс-инжинирингом - то брезгуете, батенька? В случае с джавой это фактически просто неудобный способ смотреть исходники =)

Comment: @Mints97 та ладно :) в реальной жизни в android'ом это не так просто как кажется многим, кто этого ни разу в жизни не делал... обычно все заканчивается на этапе dex2jar

Comment: @Barmaley это видели?  
http://habrahabr.ru/company/skbkontur/blog/243063/

Comment: @andreich эту конкретно не видел, но видел похожие посты. На маркете есть около полусотни индусских приложений работающих по этой схеме и выводящих на экран звонилки системный диалог с информацией о локации звонка и проч. причуды. Я сначала шел по этому пути пока не наткнулся на указанную аппу, которая делает вообще фантастические вещи. В любом случае спасибо за наводку, да еще и со ссылкой на исходники в github.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**TL;DR**
Приложение представляется системе гарнитурой для того, чтобы принимать/завершать звонки

У приложения Ultimate Call Screen HD в манифесте указано следущее:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <application ...>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.lowveld.ucs.service.OutcallService"/>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.lowveld.ucs.service.InCallService"/>
        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name="com.lowveld.ucs.receivers.PhoneReceiver">
            <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
                <action android:name="com.lowveld.ucs.action.INDIRECT_CALL"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    ...
    </application>
```

Из манифеста видно, что `PhoneReceiver` получает первым интенты от системы про исходящий/входящий звонок. Далее он делегирует обработку сервисам `InCallService` и `OutcallService`, которые отображают необходимый интерфейс для управления и используют `AudioManager` для передачи голоса

**UPDATE:**
Откроем класс `InCallService`

```
public class InCallService extends Service implements SensorEventListener, a, b, e {
    ...
    static boolean H;
    WindowManager G;
    WindowManager.LayoutParams I;
    CallWindowView J;
    ...
    private void e(final boolean b) {
        if (b) {
            return;
        }
        this.G.addView((View)this.J, (ViewGroup$LayoutParams)this.I);
        InCallService.H = true;
    }

    private void f(final boolean b) {
        if (!b) {
            return;
        }
        if (this.J.getWindowToken() != null) {
            this.G.removeView((View)this.J);
        }
        InCallService.H = false;
    }

    private void t() {
        this.I = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(-1, -1, 2010, 2621600, -1);
        if (g.a("hide_status_bar", true)) {
            final WindowManager.LayoutParams i = this.I;
            i.flags |= 0x100;
        }
        else {
            this.I.type = 2003;
        }
        this.I.gravity = 80;
        if (g.a("force_full_brightness", true)) {
            this.I.screenBrightness = 1.0f;
        }
        (this.J = (CallWindowView)((LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService("layout_inflater")).inflate(2130903099, (ViewGroup)null)).a(new a(this));
        this.G = (WindowManager)this.getSystemService("window");
    }
    ...
}
```

Из этого кода видно, что приложение накрывает стандартное окно звонилки своим `CallWindowView` (для этого и необходимо разрешение `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`). Разметка для входящего звонка хранится в R.layout.two_button_frame = 2130903099

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.lowveld.ucs.ui.views.CallWindowView android:id="@id/callprompt_frame" ...>
    ...
    <RelativeLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@id/callprompt" ...>
        <RelativeLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@id/buttonblock" ...>
            ...
            <Button android:id="@id/answerbutton" android:text="@string/button_answer_call" ... />
            <Button android:id="@id/rejectbutton" android:text="@string/button_decline_call" ... />
        </RelativeLayout>
        ...
    </RelativeLayout>
</com.lowveld.ucs.ui.views.CallWindowView>
```

R.id.answerbutton = 2131558590
R.id.rejectbutton = 2131558495
В сервисе есть код:

```
public void onCreate() {
    ...
    this.t();
    this.at = (AudioManager)this.al.getSystemService("audio");
    ...
    this.f = (Button)this.J.findViewById(2131558495);
    this.e = (Button)this.J.findViewById(2131558590);
    ...
    this.J.setOnTouchListener((View$OnTouchListener)new ac(this));
    this.J.setOnKeyListener((View$OnKeyListener)new ad(this));
    this.f.setOnClickListener((View$OnClickListener)new ae(this));
    this.f.setOnLongClickListener((View$OnLongClickListener)new af(this));
    this.e.setOnClickListener((View$OnClickListener)new b(this));
    this.e.setOnLongClickListener((View$OnLongClickListener)new c(this));
    ...
}
```

При нажатии кнопки "Принять вызов" срабатывает слушатель:

```
class b implements View$OnClickListener {
    final InCallService a;

    b(final InCallService a) {
        super();
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void onClick(final View view) {
        ...
        if (this.a.a(this.a.al)) {
            this.a.ak.a(this.a.al);
            ...
        }
        else {
            final Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");           intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.lowveld.ucshdlicense"));
            intent.setFlags(268435456);
            this.a.startActivity(intent);
            this.a.d();
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Который передает управление в данный класс:

```
public class a {
    Boolean a;
    Boolean b;

    public a() {
        super();
        this.a = false;
        this.b = false;
    }

    private void a(final Context context, final int n, final boolean b) {
        new Thread(new b(this, n, b, context)).start();
    }

    private void a(final Context context, final boolean b) {
        this.a = g.a("isHeadsetOn", false);
        this.b = ((AudioManager)context.getSystemService("audio")).isWiredHeadsetOn();
        while (true) {
            Label_0065: {
                if (!g.a("root_activate_answer", false)) { //можно ли использовать рут-права
                    break Label_0065;
                }
                try {
                    this.b();
                    final int n = 0;
                    if (n != 0) {
                        this.b(context, b); //рут-права отсутствуют/нельзя использовать
                    }
                    return;
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    final int n = 1;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            final int n = 1;
            continue;
        }
    }

    private void b(final Context context, final boolean b) {
        if (context != null) {
            if (!j.b()) { API < 16
                final Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG");
                intent.addFlags(1073741824);
                intent.putExtra("state", 2);
                intent.putExtra("name", "Headset");
                context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, (String)null);
            }
            final Intent intent2 = new Intent("android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON");
            intent2.putExtra("android.intent.extra.KEY_EVENT", (Parcelable)new KeyEvent(0, 79)); // шлем действие ACTION_DOWN с кодом KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK
            context.sendBroadcast(intent2, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
            final Intent intent3 = new Intent("android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON");
            intent3.putExtra("android.intent.extra.KEY_EVENT", (Parcelable)new KeyEvent(1, 79)); // шлем действие ACTION_UP с кодом KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK
            context.sendBroadcast(intent3, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
            if (!this.a && !this.b && !j.b()) {
                final Intent intent4 = new Intent("android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG");
                intent4.addFlags(1073741824);
                intent4.putExtra("state", 0);
                intent4.putExtra("name", "Headset");
                context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent4, (String)null);
            }
            if (b && j.b()) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    void a() {
        try {
            final DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su").getOutputStream());
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("input keyevent " + Integer.toString(6) + "\n");
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            dataOutputStream.close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public void a(final Context context) { //вызывается из слушателя
        if (j.a()) { // API >= 21
            this.a(context, 79, true);
            return;
        }
        this.a(context, true);
    }

    void b() {
        try {
            final DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su").getOutputStream());
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("input keyevent " + Integer.toString(5) + "\n"); //поднимает трубку
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            dataOutputStream.close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ну вот наконец-то - уже теплее... А есть идеи как `InCallService` и `OutCallService` находят дорогу к собственно интерфейсу звонилки? Корень то в этом. Причем прога ведь не меняет никак сам функционал звонилки, а лишь подменяет кнопки и фон.

Comment: @Barmaley готов анализ приложения. Получилось много, но суть вынес в начало ответа

Comment: Это супер! Done.

Answer (score 3):

Я не знаю как это сделано в этом приложении, на которое вы ссылаетесь. Однако, если бы я захотел сделать что нибудь такое, я бы поступил так:

1. Перехватывать события входящего и исходящего звонков, а также другие события если они нужны для обработки звонка - как это делать есть не мало ссылок, включая и в ответах в этом вопросе.

Вот ещё одна - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990590/how-to-detect-phone-call-broadcast-receiver-in-android

2. Создать красивый настраиваемый View для отображения происходящего. Сделать настройки, позволяющие выбирать фото по номеру телефона, и устанавливать его в фон, распологать кнопки сверху/снизу и т.д. Здесь можно проявить фантазию и навыки дизайнера интерфейсов - делайте что хотите, добавляйте соц. сети, фотки, аватарки, рейтинги - чего хотите, того и добавляйте.
3. Обрабатывать действия пользователя, аналогично приложению по умолчанию.

В одном из комментов вы пишите так:

> Причем прога ведь не меняет никак сам функционал звонилки, а лишь подменяет кнопки и фон.

Я бы сказал что прога не подменяет кнопки и фон, а полностью повторяет функционал "звонилки". Они просто воссоздали всё что было, добавили стилей и прочих настроек, так чтобы конечный пользователь мог менять что хочет, когда хочет.

4. Почитал немного тем по вопросу. Действительно многое с первого раза не правильно понял. Однако, ничего же не мешает отображать наш красивый View поверх стандартной звонилки?

Comment: вы даже не понимаете всю глубину своего незнания (чуть не сказал невежества) и только это останавливает меня от минусования вашего ответа:
1) Вы не сможете свой красиво собранный `View` подставить на место звонилки
2) Вы не сможете заменить системную звонилку (без рута)
3) Описываемый вами хак про `android:priority` - известен 100 лет, правда он в новых версиях не работает
4) Сказки про то что с *Если на каком-то устройстве максимальный приоритет уже установлен - ваше приложение на таком устройстве просто не будет вызвано* - оставлю на вашей совести.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869314/can-an-activity-receive-an-unordered-broadcastincoming-call-intent-before-syst - видимо не совсем на место звонилки, а скорее поверх неё.

Comment: В описании приложения есть такое: 
"- You can ALWAYS go back to the default phone interface during a call, simply by pressing the phone "Back" while on a call" - если можно вернуться к обычной звонилке одной кнопкой - возможно эта кнопка просто убирает верхний "слой"

Comment: Подредактировал ответ. В последней ссылке в комментах - принятый ответ описывает как сделать чтобы ваш View был поверх звонилки по-умолчанию. Судя по всему он просто запускается с некоторой задержкой.

Comment: Почитал ещё по теме - в общем при звонке отправляется Broadcast, который перехватывают все приложения с нужными правами. Отменить запрос нельзя, так как он не упорядоченный. Есть куча примеров кода как люди добавляют и выводят какую-либо информацию поверх стандартной звонилки. Если пойти дальше - есть примеры кода которые полностью накладываются поверх этой звонилки - её даже не видно.

Answer (score 2):

Так там по по моему отдельный специальный микроконтроллер обрабатывает аудиопоток от звонка и это не тот ARM процессор на котором собственно работает само устройство. К нему даже через NDK нельзя явно пробраться.

А через Javу видимо только можно поменять стандартный интерфейс и и[спользовать Intent.ACTION_CALL как там и написано](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029183/android-dialer-application) и как видимо и делает Ultimate Call Screen HD тоже.

Вот примеры тредов, где это обсуждалось:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/HNA-j0KnfII

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/AbU85mtDgQw/q_V_ACV1724J

Правда они от 2009 года, но не думаю что ситуация с железом внезапно изменилась.

Вот похоже [описание шины](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLIMbus) по которой осуществляется аудиопередача:

Comment: Да мне аудио тракт не нужен - мне нужно просто заменить фон на звонилке.

Comment: А понял, ну там видимо просто полноэкранная активити у которой есть все привелегии на звонки и к которой приделан весь нужный интерфейс . Но больше конкретно по реализации ничего не могу сказать.