# Возможно ли изменить интерфейс звонка?

Tags: java, android

Хотел изменить интерфейс страницы набора номера и звонка. Перерыл везде, нигде об этом не говорится или не правильно искал.

Вопрос: Возможно ли? Если да то подскажите куда копать.

Comment: Да это возможно. Начинайте [копать отсюда](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416547/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-android)

Comment: Извините, но где вы видите дубликат. Там про входящие вызовы а тут про набор номера, то есть где цифры!

Comment: Да, согласен - поторопился

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам надо создать свое приложение со своим интерфейсом наборщика (dialer) и выставить его дефолтным обработчиком набирателя в манифесте:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="tel" />    
</intent-filter>
```

Гуглите ключевые слова *android+dialer*